# Autowire doesnt wire custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have defined Custom `UserDetailService` named as `UserService` and it works fine. When i autowire it in some bean it gives me error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.restaurant.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have check all answered solution related to this on this forum but it didnt helped me to resolve my issue so i am posting the question again.

In my `rootcontext.xml` i have included "`context:annotation-config`" tag and in my `webcontext.xml` i have included `"context:component-scan base-package="com.restaurant""` . I also observed that the default constructor of `UserService` is getting called on server startup. But still autowiring it into other bean does not work. All other autowire works except custom `UserDetailService`.

Can anybody help me to resolve it as i m totally lost into this problem.

My Custom UserService class looks like:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService
{

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;    


public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {       
    User user = userDAO.findUnique("select usr from User usr where usr.isActive = 1 and usr.userName = ?", username);       
    if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }       
    return user;        
}

}
```

Comment: What is the point of injecting your custom `UserDetailsService`?

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for this exception. First you need to verify if that `@Service` annotation is properly inserted just before the class definition. If your service is UserService, the following pattern should be followed.

```
@Service
public class UserService{

 // attributes and methods 

}
```

Comment: Can you just drop the code segment over here for your custom UserService ?

Comment: I have added UserService class to the question details please have a look at it.

Comment: You are Auto Wiring UserDAO class as well. Is that class also annotated with @Repository or something similar like that before your class definition ?

Comment: As you describe the annotations and the configuration seemed not to have any error. Your other auto wiring classes are ok, but only a specific class. It's bit confusing. By the way how you try to AutoWire the UserDetailService class ?

Comment: Yes rest of auto wiring works fine...UserDetailService i am auto wiring as @Autowired UserService userService; (my custom UserDetailService class name is UserService)